# Form Sheet View Controller no Objects Visible

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

No matter what I do I cannot get any Objects that I add to my Form Sheet to show up on the iPad. When I use storyboard everything looks fine but when I run it the iPad there is nothing there. When I use the debug view hierarchy tool none of those Objects show up either.

This is only happening for Form Sheet. Is this a bug or do I need to do something special for a Form Sheet?

**UPDATE**

I tried doing this again but this time using a table view. I got even weirder results. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like in interface builder. I have a table with two sections. One section uses the Basic table cell style and in the other I have inserted a text field and type some text.

[image]

When I run this in the simulator or on a real iPad only the first section shows.

[image]

**Update 2**

I also tried doing this in a completely new project and I don't have this problem. Everything shows up as expected. I'm starting to think that there must be a bug or glitch.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. The application flow was changed by the Client and I never had to deal with this again.